# Town Hall 8 War base Attack Strategy

Tags: clash-of-clans

[image: Here]Best **WAR** attack strategy is to attack high-mid **Townhall 8** opponent whose air defense (**level 6**) is in the middle of the base.

- I cant use 3 lightning spells as the air defense is not close to one another.
- The base is spread out properly and i want to score 2-3 stars on this base

What are the good attack strategies here ?

Comment: Any chance you might be able to add a picture?  It would be very helpful to answerers.

Comment: done... please check the screenshot i uploaded.

Comment: What is your TH level and what troops/spells do you have available? looks like TH7 from your storages, but any detail counts.

Comment: Sorry :( i should've said this first...but my town hall is level 8 and i have Dragon(lvl 3), PEKKA(lvl 1) ,Archers(lvl5), Bararians(lvl 5), Wizards(lvl 4), Giants(lvl 5) , Rage Spell(lvl 3), Healing Spell (lvl 4), Lightning Spell(lvl 4), Minions (lvl 2), Hog Rider(lvl 1).

Comment: Ok, just my opinion, I don't think a dragon attack will be too effective because of those air defenses, your Pekkas might be handy, closely followed by wizards maybe to help clean up, especially for teslas. Once you get inside though, the townhall is likely to be defenseless since you will be out of range of most mortars. You could bring a few lightning spells to some mortars as soon as CC troops are out, so I would try attacking from the left to get the wizard tower, then smash through the walls to the TH, lured by CC troops when activated. I have TH7, though, no exp of TH8 attacks.

Comment: Done.(Only got 1 star)  
Started the attck from bottom of the base with 6 PEKKA's and rest Wizards and Archers COMBO...the PEKKAS got fried by his Level 5 Teslas and i hardly even reached his TH.
Even with Rage spells the PEKKAS were destroying NON-DEFENSIVE structures...
No worries though we are UP by 5 Stars in WAR.
But thanks for your suggestion it helped a lot. ;)

Comment: 6 PEKKA's are way too many, especially at lvl 1

Comment: I deployed PEKKAS with 3-3 groups..still no use :'(

Comment: Yea, Pekkas attack the closest structure regardless of the type. I suggested the left because I found it unlikely to have teslas there while they took out the wizard tower. Try getting Golem asap, you will be able to use GoWipe then.

Comment: For googlers, Prinz answer describes perfectly how to funnel your dragons to the core.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10661/should-how-do-i-attack-this-base-questions-be-considered-off-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as per the meta post, [Should “how do I attack this base?” questions be considered off-topic?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10661/4797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly late-TH8 base, and judging by your comments you're still early-to-mid TH8.  It would have been extremely difficult to get 2 or 3 stars here.  In past wars, I've found it likely to get:

- 2-3 stars on a base weaker than mine (ie, less than my TH level)
- 1-2 stars on similar level bases (ie, same TH level, less upgraded)
- 1 star (if that) on higher level bases (ie, same TH level but more upgraded, or higher TH level)

Consider this when planning your attacks - if you're trying to earn stars most efficiently, attack slightly below you on their list (ie, if you're #6 on your side, look at #6 through #10 on their side or so)

For this base, I'd probably be tempted to go ground instead of air.  The air defenses are pretty well upgraded (wizard towers and AD's, primarily) while ground defenses are kind of weaker (archer towers, cannons, although mortars are fully upgraded).

I'd probably try to run Giants on this, backed up by archers or wizards.  I'd probably go with healing spells or a mix of heal and rage, although if you know the CC troops are strong ground units, you might take lightning.  You can put some healers in your camps if you want, but with all that AD chances are good they're going to get shot down quickly.  Wall breakers aren't as critical here, since there's not a lot of layers of wall to be dealt with.

I'd start by drawing the clan castle out.  The upper right area seems like it should be possible to get close enough to draw it with a barbarian.  Checking the radius in the preview is a good way to get a closer look.  If you can't get close enough with a barb, a giant would work although it's kind of a waste.

If the CC troops are to be lightning'ed, draw them over the lower right mortar and try to take them out and the mortar out in the same go.  Otherwise, draw them into a corner and drop archers or wizards to obliterate them.

The right side and/or lower right side seem like good spots to attack from - the weakest wizard tower is here, and the goal is really to get 2 stars if possible, so we want to "wedge" into the base to hit the town hall.

I'd drop one giant to check for traps, and then drop the rest en masse.  Let them take out a swath of defenses, and then drop roughly half the ranged units in behind.  With luck, they'll spread out and strip a big hunk of the base.

As the troops spread out and the closest building to the edge of the base starts to look like the town hall, drop 1-2 ranged units until their target is the TH, and then drop the rest.

That's about the best strategy I can come up with, given your resources and level.

Answer (score 1):

10 dragons lvl3 + one dragon in CC and 3 heal spells, easy 3 stars

1. Release one dragon on Elixir collector on bottom of the screen, and one dragon on left side to attack barrack.
2. After 10sec (when left and right corner is clear) release 2+2 dragons on army camps (bottom left)
3. Now realese one dragon on dark  barrack (left side) and one dragon on right army camp.
4. Throw one heal spell on air def and gold storage, and second spell on air def and elixir storage.
5. Release your cc dragon near 2 army camps and he will go straight to th, 3rd heal spell throw on TH or where is your group of dragons
6. You won 3 stars and everybody in clan congratulates you

Good luck and have fun :)

Comment: Perfect. You have to funnel your dragons to the center. You could swap one heal with rage also.

Answer (score 0):

Use GOWIPE! My Golems are level 1, P.E.K.K.A level 2, Wizards level 5, WallBreakers level 5 and Archer level 5. I use 2 level 5 Rage Spells, 1 level 5 Healing Spell with 2 golems, 3 P.E.K.K.A, 12 Wizards, 8 WallBreakers and 1 Archer (Barbarian King level 5). By using GOWIPE, you don't need to lure out the Clan Castles troops. On the other hand, GOWIPE is expensive....the strategy costs 270,000 elixir and 900 dark elixir. Hope you like this strategy even though it may cost a bit much but it works well! Good Luck :D

NOTE: Have either and P.E.K.K.A or Wizards in your Clan Castles. DO NOT, under any circumstances, have a flying troop in your Clan Castles!! Clash On!

Answer (score 0):

I would use cc w 5 lvl 5 hogs in west corner to knock out one of highest wiz towers and prob two other weapons along that border. Use king w rage power to take out camps and other hit points along that western border...Then attack w 10 lvl 3 dragons using 3 lvl 4 rage spells when approaching the air def...timing of spells is crucial! With that wiz tower and other obstacles gone, dragon will easily take first two air def (spread them out along that side verses dropping all in one spot) and u can 3 star w at least 4-5 dragons still flying.

Answer (score -1):

Gowiwipe
Golem wizard witch(from clan players) and pekka make 2 golem 2 pekka 5 wallbreakers and the rest are wizards. Do one lightning spell and 2 rage spells and get witches from clan castle

Answer (score -1):

if you have dragons in level 3 trow 3 spells of lighting to the air defense close to the barberian king and then trow a line of dragons followed by 5 bollons level 6 in a row straight up to the two air defense in the base and its done i have done that so much it allways works